# Is there any free DBF file converter?

Tags: dbf, file-conversion, shapefile, dbase

I have only found trial versions of these converters. Does anyone know a free one? Any of the following target formats will do:

CSV, MDB, SQL, XLS

Comment: DBF as in ESRI Shapefiles (SHP), probably the same as dBase II

Comment: There's a very high probability the command line tool ogr2ogr (part of the gdal ogr utilities) can also perform this for you as it reads/writes almost all common GIS formats.

Comment: Related: [Is there any free tool to convert a file with more than 65000 registers from DBF format to CSV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018777/)

Comment: qgis can do this pretty easily. Just open the file with qgis, right click the layer and save as a csv

Comment: Github project here: https://github.com/akadan47/dbf2csv

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Microsoft Excel can open DBF files and save it on many formats

Comment: Note that with an older MS-Excel version you might run into troubles with more than 65535 records...

Comment: @Roalt Yes, that's true for Excel 2003 and older

Comment: Also, Excel tends to corrupt the dbase files if you change and save them.

Comment: At least Mac Excel 2011 doesn't open it. The OGR2OGR tool works and is the correct answer to this question.

Comment: Excel may export some cells as empty which contain special characters.

Comment: Excel also doesn't export Memo type.

Comment: Plus. Excel isn't a "free" solution.

Comment: 2017 Microsoft Excel for Mac doesn't want to open .dbf file formats.

Answer (score 11):

There's Exportizer (http://www.vlsoftware.net/exportizer/index.html) which also comes with a $$$$ "Pro" version, and DBF Viewer Plus (http://www.alexnolan.net/software/dbf.htm) by Alex Nolan.

Both are freeware, both should allow you to export to at least CSV (or more).

Marc

Comment: For anyone else interested: Exportizer is great for just peeking into a database and not doing anything real useful and seems pretty solid.  DBF Viewer Plus seemed OK but I ran into a lot of bugs when trying to create tables and fields in those tables.  Since I'm looking in on a database that I don't want to screw up, I will not be using that one and just sticking with Exportizer.

Answer (score 9):

I am able to open and convert .dbf files with [LibreOffice 3.4.4,](http://www.libreoffice.org/) and export to a variety of formats.

Comment: This is a very underrated answer. Free and simple!

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. MS Excel and SQL Server only read a part of my dbf file (2000 out of 2800 records). LibreOffice didn't have any problems. It worked well even with Latin2 encoding in dbf file.

Answer (score 3):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbf2csv

> Very simply converter between dbf and csv. You don't need any database engine.

Very simple, but worked fine for me

Comment: That converter messes up the header, especially if there is field size in header (DBASE).

Comment: Github project here: https://github.com/akadan47/dbf2csv

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article some years ago, about converting dbf's into datasets (xml readable by DataSet.ReadXml's function), however, it can be slow on big dbf's ,you can try it free though.

[Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DBF2DataSet.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[A search on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=dbf) yields some possibilities:

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbfconverter/
2. http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbmt/
3. ...

Answer (score 2):

For XLS or CSV, use OpenOffice.org.

Comment: The first row will be field names, followed by type abbreviation, field width (if applicable), and decimal places (if applicable).
There's probably an option to turn off this behavior. In the mean time if you have MS Excel, it defaults to not adding this information into the first row cells.